# Send a HTTP request to python Flask running with HTTPS certificate and key

Tags: python, http, ssl, flask

In my AWS server: I have installed pyOpenSSL and created certificate and key as well (openssl req -x509 -newkey rsa:4096 -nodes -out cert.pem -keyout key.pem -days 365).

Started my python flask as such and it is now running on https

```
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=str(5000), debug=True, use_reloader=False,
        ssl_context=('C:\\myDir\\certificate\\cert.pem', 'C:\\myDir\\certificate\\key.pem'))
```

I see:

```
* Running on https://0.0.0.0:5000/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
```

#

IN my local Server I tried HTTP Get --> https://myAWSServer:5000/myAppEntry

I see this error

```
  (Caused by SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: self signed certificate (_ssl.c:1076)')))
```

How do pass the keys to my HTTP Get ?

Comment: In short, you need to install that certificate in your local client.

Comment: Thanks can you please send me a link to do that

Comment: Please expand on what application/library & code makes the GET request from the 'local server'.  Sounds like this is not accepting a connection with a self signed cert by default, so you'll need to find a way to overide this.